# How can I display first n elements, then expand to show remaining elements?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a list of elemnts (let's say 10) and I only show first 4 on page load.
Clicking `more` will expand the list and show remaining elements.

My html code looks like this:

```
  <div id="sales">
    <div class="listContainer">
        <ul>
          <li>1</li>
          <li>2</li>
          <li>n</li>
          <li>10</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="expandSalesList">More</div>
  </div>
```

**UPDATE**

This is my current code:

```
jQuery('#sales li:gt(4)').hide();

jQuery('#sales .expandSalesList').live('click',function() {
    jQuery('#sales li').not(':visible').animate({height: 'toggle'}, 500, function() {});
});
```

How can I make the list slide up on next click?

I'm guessing it must be something like:

```
jQuery('#sales .expandSalesList').live('click',function() {
    jQuery('#sales li:lt(4)').animate({height: 'toggle'}, 500, function() {});
});
```

**UPDATE 2**

I found the answer with your help guys :)

```
jQuery('#sales .expandSalesList').live('click',function() {
    jQuery('#sales li:gt(4):visible').animate({height: 'toggle'}, 600, function() {}); // This line MUST come before next line.
    jQuery('#sales li').not(':visible').animate({height: 'toggle'}, 500, function() {});
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shows all, who isnt already visible :)

```
jQuery('#sales li:lt(4)').show();

jQuery('#sales .expandSalesList').live('click',function() {
    jQuery('#sales li').not(':visible').slideDown();
});
```

But it would be better to hide all "li higher than 4" instead showing them, so people without JS can see the results.

Like this:

```
jQuery('#sales li:gt(4)').hide();

jQuery('#sales .expandSalesList').live('click',function() {
    jQuery('#sales li').not(':visible').each( function() {

        jQuery(this).slideDown();

    });
});
```

Comment: how can I toggle this? I want it to slide up as well. See updated code.

Answer (score 2):

I have two solutions for you. In the first one all `li`'s are sliding down **separately**:

```
var n = 4;

jQuery('#sales li:lt(' + n + ')').show();

jQuery('#sales .expandSalesList').live('click',function() {
  jQuery('#sales li:gt(' + (n - 1) + ')').slideDown();
});
```

It was fairly easy, now see the solution where all `li`'s are sliding down **in a sigle move** ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lapple/rzWUR/2/)):

```
var n = 4,
    $list = jQuery('#sales ul');

$list.find('li:lt(' + n + ')').addClass('show');

jQuery('#sales .expandSalesList').live('click',function() {
    var $li = jQuery('<li />');
    $list.find('li:gt(' + (n - 1) + ')').addClass('show')
                                        .appendTo($li);

    $li.appendTo($list).slideDown(function() {
        var $this = $(this);

        $this.find('li')
             .appendTo($list)
        $this.remove();
    });

    n = $list.find('.show').length;
});
```

Mind having the following CSS:

```
.listContainer li {
    display: none;
}

.listContainer li.show {
    display: block;
}
```