# Valid HTML structure for list of links with "show more" section?

Tags: html

I have a list of links on my HTML page. I want to show 3 links by default, then have a "show more" link that the user can click on to reveal the full list. My question is about the best semantic HTML structure for this.

This is my HTML right now:

```
<ul>
<li>my link</li>
<li>my link</li>
<li>my link</li>
<li><a href="#" id="more">show more</a></li>
<span id="showmore">
<li>my link</li>
<li>my link</li>
...
</span>
</ul>
```

And I have some Javascript to hide the contents of `#showmore` initially, and to handle clicks on `#more` to show the rest of the list.

```
$("#showmore").hide();
$("#more").on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#showmore").show();
});
```

However, my question is, **how do I make this valid HTML** and also make it sensible, compact HTML?

I guess I could do the following:

```
<ul>
<li>my link</li>
<li>my link</li>
<li>my link</li>
<li><a href="#" id="more">show more</a></li>
<li class="more">my link</li>
<li class="more">my link</li>
...
</ul>
```

But it doesn't seem very efficient - I have a lot of links.

Also, it seems odd having the "show more" link as a list element, which logically it isn't, but I'm not sure where else it should go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need any special structure for that.

Just add class `.brief` to your container and this style rule:

```css
.list-container.brief li:nth-child(n+4) { display:none; }
```

```html
<div class="list-container brief">
      <ul>
        <li>my link 1</li>
        <li>my link 2</li>
        <li>my link 3</li>
        <li>my link 4</li>
        <li>my link 5</li>
      </ul>
</div>
```

and when you need to show full list remove that `.brief` class - it will show all items.

Comment: Thanks - that's a neat solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having *show more* as a list element, you could have it separately as a div under the list and then just toggle the visibility of certain list items based on your logic.

Something like this,

```
   <div class="list-container">
      <ul>
        <li>my link</li>
        <li>my link</li>
        <li>my link</li>
        <li class="more">my link</li>
        <li class="more">my link</li>
      </ul>
   </div>
   <div class="show-list">
        <a href="#" id="more">show more</a>
   </div>
```

Also, refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7914589/how-can-i-display-first-n-elements-then-expand-to-show-remaining-elements) question for reference!

Hope that helps!